# I am not able to see QH_CLIENT_WORKSTATION_NAME column, it is Null. I'm querying fron Aginity connected on Netezza server

Tags: sql, netezza, aginity

I would like to start monitoring our system closely as to see who and at what time did a user run a query.

Currently, on the tables from HIST DB, we are able to see the query Texts,  username, date, time, and client IP. But what we are more interested in is to see the client host machine name.

When we run a query requesting client hostname, the output comes as unknown.

Below is the query that we are running to get our required information:

```
SELECT *
FROM NZ_QUERY_HISTORY
```

Is there anything else that we can look at or implement for us to be able to see client machine name.

FYI: When we run: show session all; we do infact see the client host machine.

Answer (score 0):

We did our own view on top of the query history database when we started using netezza a few years ago, and it does not include the DNS name (hostname) of the client. I guess we left it out because it is empty most of the time. Another *guess* is that our DNS setup doesn’t not allow reverse DNS lookups for all IP addresses from the netezza host.

Instead we rely on:

1. the clien IP address and netezza username
2. the username&ip address on the client machine
   In total that is quite powerfull

Furthermore we add a bit if ‘pre sql’ to the connection configuration of the client tools we use (sas, powercenter, business objects, etc) and add as much info as we can to the 4 ‘client_application_*’ variables. See here for syntax: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_set.html
For powercenter we add the workflow,session and other -names...